# Spring MVC and multipart handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 4, and I have a controller with the below mapping/method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/me/bio", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse<Boolean> saveProfileBio1(Account account, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("profile") @Valid ProfileBio profileBio) throws ValidationException, IOException {
...//code here
}
```

When I submit a multipart form data request it fails with HTTP 400 Bad request with the error " org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingS ervletRequestPartException: Required request part 'profile' is not present"

Below is the raw request:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarynU961NKt3K534rCg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile"
{"profileName":"Zack Smith","profileDescription":"xxx","profileWebLink" :"www.abc","profilePictureUrl":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx-images/default.png","profileTitle":"CTO1"}
------WebKitFormBoundarynU961NKt3K534rCg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2013-11-16 21.19.59.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

As you can see the request clearly has the "profile" part. From my debugging, the issue is that the "profile" request part does not have the "Content-type" set, and DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest has the below method that requires it to be set and if it returns null the entire request fails with the above error.

```
@Override
public HttpHeaders getMultipartHeaders(String paramOrFileName) {
String contentType = getMultipartContentType(paramOrFileName);
if (contentType != null) {
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.add(CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
 return headers;
}
else {
 return null;
}
}
```

Trouble is is that I can't seem to find a way to set the content-type on a FormData submit in the browser for each part and seems to be something I can't set, and Spring seems to require it.

Any tips on how to fix this or if this is a bug?

Thanks

Comment: Have you fixed this? I think your `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile"` part just needs an additional `Content-Type: application/json` (just like the image)

Answer (score 2):

I see two options to solve the issue:

1. On the client: Add the JSON as Blob to `FormData`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535189/a/24535293). Background: Blob allows setting the content type (example with angular js):

   ```
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('profile', new Blob([angular.toJson(profile)], {
     type: "application/json"}
   ));
   ```
2. Alternativly on the server *(not recommended)*: overwrite the `getMultipartHeaders` method of `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest` and configure this in spring. If you are using `CommonsMultipartResolver` you need to overwrite it as well (due to missing dependency injection point):

   ```
   new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest() {

       @Override
       public HttpHeaders getMultipartHeaders(String paramOrFileName) {
           // your code here
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was just battling this issue and my solution was to stop using `@RequestPart` and use `@RequestParam` instead. If I'm understanding the doc for `@RequestPart` correctly, it only works out of the box for a few types (such as `MultipartFile`) but others require an `HttpMessageConverter`. Also make sure you have a `MultipartResolver` bean declared. Recommend that it return a `CommonsMultipartResolver`.