# Composing multipart/form-data with a different Content-Type on each parts with Javascript (or Angular)

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, file-upload, multipartform-data

> *Wrong question asked, see my update below*

I need to integrate my AngularJS Project with an existing RESTful API. These API consume POST request which `upload a file`, and also submit the form data in a request. Unfortunately, one of the form input requires to be in `Content-Type: Application/json`.

After search on the web, I could only `POST` with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` in which each of the parts does not have a specific `MIME`. 
How can I compose my `multipart/form-data` with a different `MIME`  for each parts in Javascript?

```
POST /api/v1/inventory
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:9000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------border

------border
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="owner"

john doe
------border
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="mybook.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------border
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="items"
Content-Type: application/json

{"name": "Book", "quantity": "12"}
------border--
```

Relevant References:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects
2. [REST - HTTP Post Multipart with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081079/rest-http-post-multipart-with-json)
3. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578846-composing-a-postable-http-request-with-multipartfo/
4. [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)
5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9082243/764592

---

## Update

Apologize for asking a wrong question. The original problem is that, I can see the server calling the logic something like,

```
func POST(req):
     owner = req.owner // This is string
     image = req.image // This is file object
     itemQuantity = req.items.quantity // Items is an object with attribute quantity
     itemName = req.items.name // Items is an object with attribute name
```

I have also managed to figure out how to submit such a post request. I will post my answer below.

Once again sorry for asking a wrong question.

Comment: The API is currently in used with the mobile apps. If the mobile apps could generate such request, I believe that web browser should be able to compose these request also.

Comment: Reference 5. show the spec that we should be able to compose this kind of request.

Comment: Not sure if I have to create a custom XMLHttpRequest from scratch for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Should this question be closed as it is a wrong question.

Answer (score 111):

According to the documentation of [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects), you can append a field with a specific content type by using the [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) constructor:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('items', new Blob([JSON.stringify({
    name: "Book",
    quantity: "12"
})], {
    type: "application/json"
}));
```

After careful observation, it turns out that it will send the part as follows:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="items"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: text/json
```

The only alternative, safe from building the whole request yourself is to pass a string value:

```
formData.append('items', '{"name": "Book", "quantity": "12"}');
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't set the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Although it set the `Content-Type: 'application/json'`, it is still wrapped under a Blob. Hence, the API reject my request. https://gist.github.com/9gix/a79a70f9b56ed252c00e#file-multipart-form-data-L6-L11

Comment: Ah, think I've made a typo; please try again.

Comment: The result of my previous comment is based on the proper syntax of Blob.

Comment: @Yeo Did you try `formData.append('items', JSON.stringify(...))` as well?

Comment: because i'm using angular, therefore this is what I use to convert into JSON `angular.toJson()` Which I believe does the same things. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

Comment: @Yeo That should be the same; it seems that with FormData you either get to upload a file with a specific content type or just a string value (without specific content type).

Comment: The fact of data being sent with `filename="blob"` is not a problem. This Blob wrapper is perfectly working for me, with Angular 2 as front end and Spring 4 as backend.

Comment: Yeap works with blob:  var blob =  new Blob([JSON.stringify(requestVo)], {
    type: "application/json"
})
  formData.append('data',blob);

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: How do I make this work in node.js, reading a file from the file-system? Blob is not available on node.

Answer (score 9):

> Mistake #1: I mistakenly assume that the **items** has to be a json, so that we can call its attribute.

Solution: To submit a multipart request that contain a file and an object like format is very simple.

```
form = new FormData();
form.append('items[name]', 'Book');
form.append('items[quantity]', 12);
form.append('image', imageFile);
form.append('owner', 'John Doe');
```

So thus the request header and body will looks something like this

```
POST /api/v1/inventory
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:9000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------border

------border
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="owner"

john doe
------border
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="mybook.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------border
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="items[name]"

Book
------border
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="items[quantity]"

12
------border--
```

Comment: Ah, you saved my day. I also assumed json had to be in a single object like a regular post data! thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing would get this to work, until I set the `Content-Type` header to undefined. In my case I am posting a file and some json.

```
public uploadFile(code: string, file):angular.IHttpPromise<any>{
    var data = `{"query":"mutation FIRMSCORECARD_CALCULATE($code:String!){ FirmScorecardMutation{ BatchCalculate(Code:$code) }}","variables":{"code":"${code}"},"operationName":"FIRMSCORECARD_CALCULATE"}`;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('operations', data);
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    let config = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    };
    let response = this.$http.post(this.graphqlUrl, formData, config);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Here is the only place where I found how to set up string variables in graphql request with javascript.