# Send file with JSON body

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

On client i have:

```
var data = new FormData();

    data.append('users',  [{ name: "John"}] );
    data.append('excel', files[0]);
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,
```

on server i next middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(multer());
```

But when i send somthing i have file and not parsed JSON body, it look like:

```
{ users: '[object Object]' }
```

Comment: And if i user JSON.stringify([{ name: "John"}]), i will be have this { users: '[{"name":"John"}]' }

Comment: are you using the latest expressjs?

Comment: Related: [Composing multipart/form-data with a different Content-Type on each parts with Javascript (or Angular)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24535189/218196)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should show the controller code. But based on what you said in your comment.

> And if i user JSON.stringify([{ name: "John"}]), i will be have this { users: '[{"name":"John"}]' }

Use:

```
JSON.stringify([{ name: "John"}])
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
{ users: JSON.parse('[{"name":"John"}]') }
```

Use `JSON.parse` on the received data.

So now you:

- send data as string
- recv data as string
- JSON.parse recv'd string to convert it back to an object

Comment: This cool, bro, but this work must do body-parser on middleware. Why he ignore JSON content?

Comment: @user3776269 can you show the code for this `{ users: '[object Object]' }`?

Comment: @majidarif: `data.append('users',  [{ name: "John"}] );`

Comment: @FelixKling no, I mean on the receiving end. The code for the controller.

Comment: @user3776269: I don't think you can have the whole body being JSON if you want to send files as well. However, if you want that, you must not use form data but set the body directly with: `data: JSON.stringify(...)`. Also make sure to send the right content type headers.

Comment: @majidarif router.post('/users', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body)
})

and i give { users: '[object Object]' }

Comment: @FelixKling On headers i have multipart/form-data content type. Also, if i use needle(module for node js) i send req, i have excellent result, parsed body and file. Code for req with needle: var data = {
        users: [{ name: "John"}],
        excel: { file: path.join(__dirname ,'fixtures/test.xlsx'),      
        content_type: 'multipart/form-data' }
    };

    needle.post(url, { multipart: true }, function(err, resp, body) {})

Comment: @user3776269: Assuming you are using https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser, did you read the README? *"This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules: [...]"* I don't know `needle`, but I'm sure it won't encode the whole payload as JSON either.