# Building a multipart form with ng-admin to post an attribute and file data to the server

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

Using [ng-admin](http://ng-admin.marmelab.com), how can you build a creation view form with two fields: a name, and a file?

The [file field type](http://ng-admin-book.marmelab.com/doc/reference/Field.html#-file-field-type) lets you easily select a file as part of a form, but it immediately posts it to an endpoint that you configure. That endpoint returns the created filename, which you can then refer to when you submit the form.

This strategy doesn't work for me. I need ng-admin to let me select a file, enter a name for the file, and then submit both pieces of data as a multipart encoded POST when I submit the form.

I think this might be possible with some clever uses of custom Angular directives, but I'm not sure about the right way to go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, ng-admin doesn't provide multipart forms. You'll have to use a custom edition view for that. Here is a pointer I found on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902727/multipart-request-with-angularjs

Comment: Thanks, @FrançoisZaninotto