# 400 Bad Request When Send Multipart Request To Spring MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am attempting to send form data with Multipart data (Image) to Spring MVC controller, but its not calling Spring controller defined and showing 400 Bad Request error when http post call in chrome console. I have referred all questions related to this in SO but i could not unlock the problem. Please find where i did mistake.

Html Code:

```
<input ng-model='file1' type="file"/>
```

AngularjS Code:

```
$scope.saveData = function (formObj) {
        $http({
            url: CONTEXT_PATH+'saveFile',
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                formData.append("file", data.files);
                return formData;
            },
            data: { model: formObj, files: $scope.file1 }
        }).then(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    };
```

Spring Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String storeAd(@RequestPart("model") String adString, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("adString > "+adString);
    return "OK";
}
```

Error in browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

Data Details in Browser:

```
Request Header:

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 24635
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvpAdhKSccplcX99W

Form Data:

model: {"emailId":"ss@ss.com",..}
file: undefined

Response Header:

Connection: close
Content-Length: 1058
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

> No exception at Server Side.

Comment: Please try to use Postman a chrome extension for Post call.

Comment: `'Content-Type': undefined` doesn't look right. Read / share the raw request as received by the server including headers. Check / share web server error logs.

Comment: @marekful i have updated additional information

Comment: Don't just look for exception, check anything written into access and error logs upon receiving the request. The Content-Type header looks good in the request header, but the `----WebKitFormBoundaryvpAdhKSccplcX99W` boundary must be present in the request body too in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using below request, I was able to upload file to a controller similar to yours.

Form Data :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryDhtDYn8BtyH0NdRW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dummy_file.xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
------WebKitFormBoundaryDhtDYn8BtyH0NdRW--
```

Request Headers :

```
POST /demo/upload?data=dummy_data HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5005
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 36563
accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:5005
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDhtDYn8BtyH0NdRW
Referer: http://localhost:5005/swagger-ui.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

You should try changing Content-Type as above as well as add boundary.

Do check out another solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545774/1776132

Answer (score 0):

Its working when i use @RequestParam instead of @RequestPart

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveFile")
public @ResponseBody String storeAd(@RequestParam ("model") String adString, @RequestParam ("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("adString > "+adString);
    return "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I needed spring web(not webflux) for this to work

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```