# Sending multipart form using Dojo xhr with both json and file upload

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dojo, form-data

I've tried to get this working but did not find any soluion. The closest to my problem is this one - [Composing multipart/form-data with a different Content-Type on each parts with Javascript (or Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535189/composing-multipart-form-data-with-a-different-content-type-on-each-parts-with-j) - but the question author stopped in between. I cannot.

So this is the story - I got webservice written in **.NET**. It is **POST** based - I have to send both - **JSON** data (with title, content, etc) and also file(s) - just uploaded from user's disc. I am sending this from **DOJO** Dialog box. What I am actually doing is create AJAX post request and send it to the server.

So I should use *'multipart/form-data'*. The problem is that I have to gather data to be send from various sources (not only data provided in form elements). My code looks something like this.

```
var values = { // here I create simple JS object with data from multiple places };
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('data', json.stringify(values));   // Object to JSON
var files = document.getElementById("files").files;
var file = files[0];
formData.append("file0", file);

xhr.post('link_to_my_service',  
{ 
    handleAs: "json",
    sync: false,
    data: formData,
    headers: {                     
         'X-Requested-With': '',
         'Content-Type': false,   
         'Accept': 'application/javascript, application/json'
    }
}) // handlers are not important
```

It goes to the service, the service accepts it ('X-Requested-With' for security passing). My request in console looks like this.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryDyeoTyKXhr5oZ1a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"    
{"key1":"value2","key2":"value1","key3":666,"key4":999}

------WebKitFormBoundaryDyeoTyKXhr5oZ1a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file0"; filename="name_of_my_file.opml"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

------WebKitFormBoundaryDyeoTyKXhr5oZ1a9--
```

And it DOES NOT WORK. It happens because of 'data' part of request not having 'Content-Type' set! And I am not able to do that in any way. Suggested solution was to create **BLOB** and then pass it the **JSON** string. But it does not work either - it adds '*Content-Type*' (skips charset though), but adds filename and also in the console I see that actual contents of this part is empty (although the same is for file - I do not know if Chrome should show me there full cotents of my file).

So now I am stuck - I do not know how to proceed. There is no way I can change the service. Does anybody got any idea how to trick Dojo to achieve my goal? And yes, I am using **Dojo 1.10**.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little bit late, but better late than never.

The link you marked as closest to your problem, delivers already a solution. (Last answer from Yeo)

So based on that answer, I would try to build up my FormData object like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();

// add the file to your form data.
formData.append('file', file);    

// create an object like structure in your form data.
for (let key in values) {
  if(values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    formData.append(`data[${key}]`, values[key]);
  }
}

// set up your post requests options.
...

let handle = xhr.post(url, options);
```

And then on the server side, you can parse this back to an object, by iterating over the requests body parts and collecting the fields you need.