# Add additional information to the PrimeNG FileUpload data transfer

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm looking to send additional information with files that are being uploaded with the primeng fileupload component. Basically, I need to know what these uploaded files are relevant to.

I can add headers in the "onBeforeSend" function like the Authorization code as in the example below.  Where could I add additional information e.g. 'DocumentID': 'A123'

```
onBeforeSend(event) {
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getAccessToken());
}
```

Anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `onBeforeSend` event of `primeng fileupload` control there is an object called `event.formData`, you can use this object to customize the request with aditional information. I was able to implement this functionality successfully in current project i'm working on.

In `component.ts` file:

```
    onBeforeSend(event) {
       event.xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`);
       event.formData.append('DocumentID', 'A123');
    }
```

In `template.html` file:

```
    <p-fileUpload name="test[]" 
                  [url]="url_test" 
                  (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)" 
                  accept="image/*" 
                  maxFileSize="5000000" 
                  withCredentials="true">
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks. I have it working for some time now so I agree that is the correct answer!

Comment: This no longer works with primeng 7.x. Still trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Which is the problem? the `event` or the `formData` object?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sending the entity alongside the files on my request as follows (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535293/961652) for more info)

We can **send the Entity serialized as JSON** in a Blob inside our [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) using [the correct Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535189/composing-multipart-form-data-with-a-different-content-type-on-each-parts-with-j) 'application/json'. With this we can include nested objects, add fields to our Entity -and we won't have to change the Resource Controller method signature with every new field-

curso-update.component.ts

```
private onBeforeSend(event) {
    const token = this.localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken') || this.sessionStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken');
    if (!!token) {
        event.xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer  ${token}`);
    }
    event.formData.append('curso', new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.curso)], { type: 'application/json' }));
}
```

change the Resource Controller accordingly

CursoResource.java

```
@PostMapping("/cursos/archivos")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Curso> createCurso(@Valid @RequestPart(value = "curso") Curso curso, 

@RequestPart("archivos[]")MultipartFile[] archivos) {
...
Curso result = this.cursoService.save(curso);
...
}
```