# Sending multiple content type in single request

Tags: json, angular, http-headers

I'm trying to send multiple files with additional JSON data to the API. The API seems to support multiple content types.

How can I form the header with two content types:

1. Multipart form data (for files)
2. application/json (for other json params)

Comment: You can't. There would be no way of specifying which part if JSON and which part is multipart. There's no reason you can't send your JSON as a string value within the multipart request though

Comment: multi-part is already _multiple parts_. So the files go in one part and the JSON in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jack's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/ja%CD%A2ck) answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535293/9404093, I set up the following using different content types:

```js
uploadFile(request: FileUploadRequest, file: File): Observable<FileUploadResponse> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('details', new Blob(
      [JSON.stringify(request)],
      { type: "application/json" }
    ));
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    formData.append('contentType', file.type);

    return this.http.post<FileUploadResponse>(FILES_URI, formData);
  }
```

By using a Blob, you can assign a content type to the blob content (json).

Note this works with a Java Spring backend controller as well:

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestPart FileUploadRequest details, @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
    // TODO: the stuff
}
```